# Rare ConcurrentModificationException in JBoss Resteasy service

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb, resteasy, concurrentmodification

I have implemented Resteasy service which is working under Apache Tomcat. It works fine, but sometimes, when sending request to service, very rarely I receive such crazy error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister$1.next(Lister.java:288)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:139)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.writeTo(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:62)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:118)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:99)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:224)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Are any ideas about reason for such error or ways, how to reproduce/fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

There are several answers where you, guys, suggest me to implement `Synchronized` collections inside my beans. It is not a way, because:

1) I generate my beans from XSD using standard generators. I have approx. 100 different beans and I do not want to change them all manually

2) There is not any mention about need of synchonized collections neither in `JAXB` docs, neither in `RESTEasy` docs.

Comment: i think you try to delete an item from `ArrayList` with iterator. Can you post full stack trace including **caused by** entries.

Comment: @erencan I have posted full stack trace, dear. If you will look more carefully you will see, that cause is not in my code.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread executed at a time? or does the service work on shared data?

Comment: @erencan as I said in my question, I run this service under Apache Tomcat, so sure: it works in concurrent enviroment. There is no evident shared data.

Comment: Well, I guess all the source code for everything in the stack trace should be available, so it should be just a matter of reading all the methods mentioned and looking for some shared data...

Comment: ArrayList is not a concurrent data structure, then Vector should be used in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @erencan Dear, I know a lot about synchornized collections, thanks. This question is not about them. B.t.w `Vector` is not good decision.

Comment: @Andremoniy - Please provide the jaxb annotated class you attempting to bind and the resteasy method you are calling. There are a number of scenarios utilizing JAXB models that can cause this issue.

Comment: Actually I can't do that, it is Company's property code. And I don't believe that my issue is somewhere inside my JAXB model.

Comment: @Andremoniy Of course the error stack does not show you code, since it is using refection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Resteasy is in the process of generating an XML response, but the object tree that was passed to the JAXB marshaller has been modified by another thread in the application.

A list in the marshalled object tree has been modified by another thread, and so when the marshaller goes through the list, it causes a ConcurrentModificationException.

Is it normal that there are two application threads accessing the same bean, are there some beans stored in static variables for example ?

Try turning on -Djaxb.debug=true to get further info on which bean property it's causing the problem. It might not always be the same property causing the error.

Another way of identifying the property is putting a breakpoint in the line that throws the CME, and checking what is the type of the elements of the list is.

If the beans in the application are intended to be accessed by multiple threads, then it's necessary to make the bean classes thread safe but based on what you mention there is no evident shared state - so your beans should only be accessed by one thread at a time.

You can always take a few heap dumps and search in eclipse memory analyzer for which threads are referencing objects of the list/lists causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is the ArrayList being created as a synchronized collection? You may want to use this approach to avoid concurrency issues. Note the synchronized recommendation while iterating:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)

```
public static <T> Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c)
```

Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) collection backed by the specified collection. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing collection is accomplished through the returned collection.

It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when iterating over it:

```
Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
   ...
synchronized (c) {
    Iterator i = c.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
       foo(i.next());
}
```

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

The returned collection does not pass the hashCode and equals operations through to the backing collection, but relies on Object's equals and hashCode methods. This is necessary to preserve the contracts of these operations in the case that the backing collection is a set or a list.

The returned collection will be serializable if the specified collection is serializable.

Comment: Hi! You want to tell me about synchronized colletions? Many thanks for that! But this issue is not about how to synchronize collection, this is about internal issue in jBoss resteasy library, not about my own collections in my code.

Comment: @Andremoniy Some sample code from your implementation of resteasy and the version of resteasy would be more helpful than a vague exception.

Comment: No, my question was about ideas, how I can investigate this issue. I can not provide "sample" code, because this is in particular my project, which I can not publish

Comment: Did you at least try using a synchronizedCollection?

Comment: I do not understand, why I should use synchronized collections in my simple beans, only because they are parsed by JAXB??

Answer (score 0):

Your bean's `ArrayList` property is not supporting concurrency.

If you check the source code ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/reflect/Lister.java#288)):

```
public static final class CollectionLister<BeanT,T extends Collection> extends Lister<BeanT,T,Object,T> {

        public ListIterator iterator(T collection, XMLSerializer context) {
            final Iterator itr = collection.iterator();
            return new ListIterator() {
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return itr.hasNext();
                }
                public Object next() {
                    return itr.next();
                }
            };
        }
 }
```

You will notice the line throw error is `Collection.iterator.next()`. Which mean that the list is changed while JAXB is loop through the list property.

To solve this, try to use [Collections.synchronizedList(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) to create synchronized list.

Example:

```
public class Bean {

    private List<String> phones = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    public void setPhones(List<String> phones) {
        if(phones == null) {
            this.phones = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            this.phones = Collections.synchronizedList(phones);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well,actually I'm on my previous opinion:  
I do not understand, why I should use synchronized collections in my simple beans, only because they are parsed by JAXB?? Where is such claim in JABX or RESTeasy docs?