# ConcurrentModificationException occasionally

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a JavaSE library (and full access to the source code) that occasionally throws a ConcurrentModificationException when executed by a Stateless EJB during load tests.

The application server is [thorntail 2.3.0](https://docs.thorntail.io/2.3.0.Final/) running on JDK 11.0.2

Originally, the Exception happened during marshaling (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300792/rare-concurrentmodificationexception-in-jboss-resteasy-service)), but I added calls to the following method to see where the Exception could also occur:

```
    private static Object deepCopy(Object object) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream outputStrm = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
            outputStrm.writeObject(object); // line 164 in MyClass
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
            return objInputStream.readObject();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is an example Stacktrace of the Exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:900)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at com.my.java.se.library.MyClass.deepCopy(MyClass.java:164)
    at com.my.java.se.library.MyClass.someMethod(MyClass.java:132)
    at com.my.thorntail.app.SomeStatelessEJB.callToSeLib(SomeStatelessEJB.java:50)
   ....
```

I added calls to `deepCopy()` at several places of `someMethod()`, and the Exception sometimes occurs at the very end of `someMethod()`, sometimes somewhere in the middle.
I don't know what I should conclude from this. Is some other thread deciding that it wants to modify the object?

Now, the entire JavaSE library does not contain any statements regarding threads, so it is purely single-threaded. And as far as I understand, the only possible option for a ConcurrentModificationException happening in a single thread would be if the Array is modified while iterating over it. However, this is not the case.

What other reasons could there possibly be for this Exception?
How can I track down where things might be going wrong?

**Edit in response to Kayaman's answer:**

The JavaSE library is really also just part of the code we develop, so both the calling code and the library code are equally likely to be the culprit.

I concluded from the experiments with the `deepCopy()` method, which lead to ConcurrentModificationExceptions being thrown inside the library, that the error is located there. But that might be wrong.

Here is the structure of the calling code, that is running in many threads simultaneously during the load test. While trying to reduce the code to the essential parts, I realized a possible problem:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeStatelessEJB {

   private MyClass myClass;

   public void callToSeLib() {
      myClass = getMyClassInstance(); // we are reusing the same MyClass object !!
      myClass.someMethod();
   }

}
```

I will adjust the code to not longer reuse this object, and then report back here.

**Edit to report progress**

It was indeed the reuse of the MyClass object.

The fix was to only reuse parts of the MyClass Object (the expensive to create parts) and recreate the inexpensive and problematic parts for every request.

Thanks for forcing me to condense the code to the bare minimum in order to explain the situation here. During this process I noticed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace tells you that at some point you're serializing an `ArrayList`, which is being modified at the same time. The relevant code in `ArrayList`

```
    // Write out element count, and any hidden stuff
    int expectedModCount = modCount;
    s.defaultWriteObject();

    // Write out size as capacity for behavioural compatibility with clone()
    s.writeInt(size);

    // Write out all elements in the proper order.
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        s.writeObject(elementData[i]);
    }

    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
```

So either you have objects being mutated from different threads, or you've managed to write code that causes the list to be mutated in the same thread through a different way. In a single threaded case it would be possible to get this if the elements had their own `writeObject()` that would modify the list (of course this would be a horrible thing to do in code).

You say that the library doesn't use threads, but you're still using threads based on your environment, so let's not throw out the simplest explanation just yet.

Maybe you should show how you're calling `MyClass.someMethod()`, since that's your code and that's always the first suspect (don't blame libraries before blaming yourself).